# Does Power BI have a web designer to be exposed to end users?

Tags: powerbi

I have an app with a reporting module and multiple organisations. I need to leverage Power BI to allow my end users to have access to workspaces where they can create/edit reports. Not just view or embed. Any feature in Power BI to expose a web-based report designer to end users?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow users to create and edit embedded reports.

> Power BI embedded analytics allows you to create, edit, and save embedded reports. A report can be created based on an existing dataset, or you can edit an existing report. You can also save the report after it was created or edited.

[Create, edit, and save an embedded report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers)

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer here or delete this altogether. [answer]

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer to give more than a "yes" answer.